# Data Structure which maintains spacing for similar elements

Tags: data-structures, queues

I want a queue like data structure in which a new element inserted has to be some elements away from a related element.

While reading from this data structure, related elements should only be read after some time.

Suppose ***X*** is inserted. Then ***Y*** which is related to ***X*** should only be inserted at a position which is ***k*** elements away from ***X***.

The relation is my own condition and can be found in ***O(1)***.

If a stream of elements are coming to be inserted we can hold related elements and then when some unrelated elements are inserted such that the distance criteria is fulfilled it should insert the related element.

So is there some type of data structure which can achieve this.

Comment: With data structure questions, it is helpful for you to state the exact functions you want, what time they should run in, and what they should do. As stated this question is unclear.

Comment: Is your relation an equivalence relation?  Can you produce canonical representatives of each equivalence class?  Or is the relation just a black-box function?